# Custom serializer not working in Web API 2 for oData 4 when the URL contains $select

Tags: select, serialization, asp.net-web-api2, odata

I implemented a custom serializer by inheriting `ODataEntityTypeSerializer`. The serializer sets the value of `MessageStateName by getting the name of` BayStateEnum`from the value of`MessageState`.

It works well only except when the URL contains `$select`. I debugged the code and found it was executed and `entityInstanceContext.EntityInstance` had the correct value, but `entityInstanceContext.EdmModel`, which was of type `System.Web.OData.Query.Expressions.SelectExpandBinder.SelectSome<SmartComms.Archive.Api.Models.BayMessageModel>`, still had an empty `MessageStateName`.

```cs
public class CustomEntitySerializer : ODataEntityTypeSerializer
{
    public CustomEntitySerializer(ODataSerializerProvider serializerProvider)
        : base(serializerProvider)
    {
    }
    public override ODataEntry CreateEntry(SelectExpandNode selectExpandNode, EntityInstanceContext entityInstanceContext)
    {
        if (entityInstanceContext.EntityInstance is SmartLinkInfoModel)
        {
            var smartLinkInfo = entityInstanceContext.EntityInstance as SmartLinkInfoModel;
            if (smartLinkInfo.ModemIMEI != null)
            {
                smartLinkInfo.ModemIMEIString = "0x" + string.Join(string.Empty, smartLinkInfo.ModemIMEI.Select(b => (b - 48).ToString()));
            }
            if (smartLinkInfo.SmartLinkHardwareId != null)
            {
                smartLinkInfo.SmartLinkHardwareIdString = "0x" + string.Join(string.Empty, smartLinkInfo.SmartLinkHardwareId.Select(b => b.ToString()));
            }
            if (smartLinkInfo.XbeeSourceId != null)
            {
                smartLinkInfo.XbeeSourceIdString = "0x" + string.Join(string.Empty, smartLinkInfo.XbeeSourceId.Select(b => b.ToString()));
            }
        }
        else if (entityInstanceContext.EntityInstance is BayMessageModel)
        {
            var bayMessage = entityInstanceContext.EntityInstance as BayMessageModel;
            bayMessage.MessageStateName = Enum.GetName(typeof(BayStateEnum), bayMessage.MessageState);
        }
        return base.CreateEntry(selectExpandNode, entityInstanceContext);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code to change the entityInstanceContext.EntityInstance is right, but it won't change the result of select, you can see

```
object propertyValue = entityInstanceContext.GetPropertyValue(structuralProperty.Name);
```

in `ODataEntityTypeSerializer` 's `CreateStructuralProperty` method, you should override this method, if the `structuralProperty.Name` is `MessageStateName`, then use `(entityInstanceContext.EntityInstance as BayMessageModel).MessageStateName`

Comment: Did you return base.CreateStructuralProperty? If you do that, nothing will change, just implement the whole method, modify propertyValue when the property is MessageStateName

Comment: I see. So basically I need to copy the source code of the method plus add an "if" block for MessageStateName property?

Comment: I tried copying the source code, but at the end of the base class, ODataEdmTypeSerializer.CreateProperty was called and it is internal, which means I can't use it in my code.

Comment: Waht about get the OdataProperty through original method and modify the value.